# Get value of a key in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails and I'm having some trouble trying to extract a key value from an array of hashes (@sorted) when using `options_from_collection_for_select` in my html.haml file.

So far I've tried

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@sorted, "#{@sorted['id']}", 
"#{@sorted['name']}")

options_from_collection_for_select(@sorted, @sorted['id'], @sorted['name'])
```

But both give me a "Can't convert string to integer" error I've tried calling `to_i` but the error still persists.

Array of Hashes (@sorted)

```
@sorted => [{"id"=>"51a7ba4154b3289da800000f", "name"=>"Book1", "count"=>8},
{"id"=>"519d24ed54b328e512000001", "name"=>"Book2", "count"=>5},
{"id"=>"5258917b54b32812cd000003", "name"=>"Book3", "count"=>1}]
```

Comment: please show us a part of your `@sorted` hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `options_for_select`:

```rb
options_for_select(@sorted.map{|hash| [hash["id"],hash["name"]]})
```

Comment: I did this manipulation in my controller which makes things a lot cleaner on the haml end but yes this worked. I got it to work before I saw your answer but you definitely get the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you have an array, it is made up of multiple elements, and the methods you call on it are array methods, not methods for the elements inside.

In this case, each element is a hash, so your array looks like the following:

```
[ {"id" => 1, "name" => "Name 1"}, {"id" => 2, "name" => "Name 2" ]
```

The class itself is an array. You can index in to an array like so:

```
myArray[1]
```

This method takes an integer and finds the `n`th element. So doing:

```
@sorted[1]
```

Would return this hash element:

```
{"id" => 2, "name" => "Name 2"}
```

And *now* you can call hash methods on it. This is why you were getting that error, because the `Array#[]` method assumed you were giving it an integer to index in to the array, but you were giving it a string - a string that could not be converted in to an integer.

So in your particular case, you probably mean to do:

```
@sorted.first["id"], @sorted.first["name"]
```

(Doing `@sorted.first` is an alternative to `@sorted[0]` to get the first element in an array)

Comment: How would this iterate through to the remaining array elements? If my `options_from_collection_for_select` has `@sorted.first["id"], @sorted.first["name"]` wouldn't it always be just displaying the first element?

Comment: If you want more information on how to use that method, see the documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select But my response was more so in regards to your Ruby-use issue.